# Lotus notes - how to avoid copying to clipboard when I select the emails

Tags: email, lotus-notes

I need handle more than hundreds of emails every day, and most of them are not required, so I need delete some of them by manual selection.

But when I select hundreds of emails, it will automatically copy documents to the clipboard, and normally it will make a big delay. and it make more email process feeling not so good.

Is there any way to avoid automatically coping emails to clipboard when I select emails?

My notes client is v8.5.

Comment: There's no need to copy emails to the clipboard when you select them. What do you do since this happens?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using Ctrl-X to delete the messages. That's actually the shortcut for 'Cut', not for 'Delete'. You should just use the Delete key insteaad, and without the shift key, because Shift-Delete also cuts to the clipboard.